# How to pass textbox value in scriptData, which is appending dynamic in JQuery File 'uploadify' plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, uploadify

I have added **textbox** in '**uploadify**' plugin for getting file description from user, and passing it to **scriptData**.

```
function loadSwf(){    
    $("#fileuploader").fileUpload({
            'uploader':  "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/FileUpload/uploader.swf")",
            'cancelImg':  "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/clearBtn.png")",
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            //'buttonImg' : "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/attachDoc.png")",
            'script': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/Upload/")",   
            'folder': "@Url.Content("~/Documents/")",
            //'fileDesc': 'Documents Files',
            'fileExt': '*.pdf;*.doc;*.ppt;*.xls',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false,                 
            'scriptData': {'Description': $('[id="DescriptionTxt"]').val()}
        });
}
```

via controller `MVC3`.. 
[image: Multiple File Upload]
There the problem is i have all textbox with same " **ID and Name** " so how to isolate  or get value of each textbox fields??

```
var flashVer = -1;
var activityId = $('[id="ActivityID"]').val();
if (navigator.plugins != null && navigator.plugins.length > 0) {
    if (navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]) {
        var swVer2 = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] ? " 2.0" : "";
        var flashDescription = navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash" + swVer2].description;
        var descArray = flashDescription.split(" ");
        var tempArrayMajor = descArray[2].split(".");
        var versionMajor = tempArrayMajor[0];
        var versionMinor = tempArrayMajor[1];
        var versionRevision = descArray[3];
        if (versionRevision == "") {
            versionRevision = descArray[4]
        }
        if (versionRevision[0] == "d") {
            versionRevision = versionRevision.substring(1)
        }
        else {
            if (versionRevision[0] == "r") {
                ersionRevision = versionRevision.substring(1);
                if (versionRevision.indexOf("d") > 0) {
                    versionRevision = versionRevision.substring(0, versionRevision.indexOf("d"))
                }
            }
        }
        var flashVer = versionMajor + "." + versionMinor + "." + versionRevision
    }
}
else {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        var version;
        var axo;
        var e;
        try {
            axo = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7");
            version = axo.GetVariable("$version")
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
        flashVer = version.replace("WIN ", "").replace(",", ".")
    }
}
flashVer = flashVer.split(".")[0];
if (jQuery) {
    (function (a) {
        a.extend(a.fn,
        {
            fileUpload: function (b) {
                if (flashVer >= 9) {
                    a(this).each(function () {
                        settings = a.extend({
                            uploader: "uploader.swf",
                            script: "uploader.php",
                            folder: "",
                            height: 30,
                            width: 110,
                            cancelImg: "cancel.png",
                            wmode: "opaque",
                            scriptAccess: "sameDomain",
                            fileDataName: "Filedata",
                            displayData: "percentage",
                            onInit: function () { },
                            onSelect: function () { },
                            onCheck: function () { },
                            onCancel: function () { },
                            onError: function () { },
                            onProgress: function () { },
                            onComplete: function () { }
                        }, b);
                        var d = location.pathname;
                        d = d.split("/");
                        d.pop();
                        d = d.join("/") + "/";
                        var f = "&pagepath=" + d;
                        if (settings.buttonImg) {
                            f += "&buttonImg=" + escape(settings.buttonImg)
                        }
                        if (settings.buttonText) {
                            f += "&buttonText=" + escape(settings.buttonText)
                        }
                        if (settings.rollover) {
                            f += "&rollover=true"
                        }
                        f += "&script=" + settings.script;
                        f += "&folder=" + escape(settings.folder);
                        if (settings.scriptData) {
                            var g = "";
                            for (var c in settings.scriptData) {
                                g += "&" + c + "=" + settings.scriptData[c]
                            }
                            f += "&scriptData=" + escape(g)
                        }
                        f += "&btnWidth=" + settings.width;
                        f += "&btnHeight=" + settings.height;
                        f += "&wmode=" + settings.wmode;
                        if (settings.hideButton) {
                            f += "&hideButton=true"
                        }
                        if (settings.fileDesc) {
                            f += "&fileDesc=" + settings.fileDesc + "&fileExt=" + settings.fileExt
                        }
                        if (settings.multi) {
                            f += "&multi=true"
                        }
                        if (settings.auto) {
                            f += "&auto=true"
                        }
                        if (settings.sizeLimit) {
                            f += "&sizeLimit=" + settings.sizeLimit
                        }
                        if (settings.simUploadLimit) {
                            f += "&simUploadLimit=" + settings.simUploadLimit
                        }
                        if (settings.checkScript) {
                            f += "&checkScript=" + settings.checkScript
                        }
                        if (settings.fileDataName) {
                            f += "&fileDataName=" + settings.fileDataName
                        }
                        if (a.browser.msie) {
                            flashElement = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="' + settings.width + '" height="' + settings.height + '" id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Uploader" class="fileUploaderBtn"><param name="movie" value="' + settings.uploader + "?fileUploadID=" + a(this).attr("id") + f + '" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="' + settings.wmode + '" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="' + settings.scriptAccess + '"><param name="swfversion" value="9.0.0.0" /></object>'
                        }
                        else {
                            flashElement = '<embed src="' + settings.uploader + "?fileUploadID=" + a(this).attr("id") + f + '" quality="high" width="' + settings.width + '" height="' + settings.height + '" id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Uploader" class="fileUploaderBtn" name="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Uploader" allowScriptAccess="' + settings.scriptAccess + '" wmode="' + settings.wmode + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />'
                        }
                        if (settings.onInit() !== false) {
                            a(this).css("display", "none");
                            if (a.browser.msie) {
                                a(this).after('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Uploader"></div>');
                                document.getElementById(a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").outerHTML = flashElement
                            }
                            else {
                                a(this).after(flashElement)
                            } 
                            a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + "Uploader").after('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + 'Queue" class="fileUploadQueue"></div>')
                        }
                        a(this).bind("rfuSelect",
                        {
                            action: settings.onSelect
                        },
                        function (j, h, i) {
                            if (j.data.action(j, h, i) !== false) {
                                var k = Math.round(i.size / 1024 * 100) * 0.01;
                                var l = "KB";
                                if (k > 1000) {
                                    k = Math.round(k * 0.001 * 100) * 0.01;
                                    l = "MB"
                                }
                                var m = k.toString().split(".");
                                if (m.length > 1) {
                                    k = m[0] + "." + m[1].substr(0, 2)
                                }
                                else {
                                    k = m[0]
                                }
                                if (i.name.length > 20) {
                                    fileName = i.name.substr(0, 20) + "..."
                                }
                                else {
                                    fileName = i.name
                                }
                                a("#" + a(this).attr("id") + "Queue").append('<div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + h + '" class="fileUploadQueueItem"><div class="cancel"><a href="javascript:$(\'#' + a(this).attr("id") + "').fileUploadCancel('" + h + '\')"><img src="' + settings.cancelImg + '" border="0" /></a></div><span class="fileName">Document Name :' + fileName + "</br>Documents Size : (" + k + l + ')</span><span class="percentage">&nbsp;</span></br><div class="Description">Description : <input type="textbox" id="des" name="des" class="des"></div><div class="fileUploadProgress" style="width: 100%;"><div id="' + a(this).attr("id") + h + 'ProgressBar" class="fileUploadProgressBar" style="width: 1px; height: 3px;"></div></div></div>')
                            }
                        });
```

The last line contains the code where i have added div with class **description** and with **textbox with id & name="des"**

Comment: Where's the code that generates the multiple upload boxes? We can modify that to make the ids unique, which is a good practice in general.

Comment: @AustinMullins I have shared the plugin code with hav Div added for Textbox At lastline with <Div class="description">